# FnSplit not working for SQL stored procedure to take multiple parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, multiple-value

I have a stored procedure that currently takes in one value(ChainId) for a parameter. I am trying to allow the user to select multiple values of(ChainId). My where statement is below. Could someone help point me in a better direction than I am going now. Currently the query will run and return no data if I select multiple values for the parameter.

```
WHERE EndAuth is null AND CL.CHIND in(
SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.FnSplit(@ChainId, ','))
ORDER BY CL.CHIND
```

Comment: First of all which DBMS are you using? Please tag accordingly. Second, make sure that your split function works as intended (and doesn't return NULL values). You can try with `SELECT * FROM dbo.FnSplit('first value, second value', ',')`. Third, since this isn't your full query, make sure that there is no other condition or join that's actually filtering your rows.

Comment: Show the exact input to `@chainID` when you select multiple values.  Then show the exact output of `SELECT [Value] FROM dbo.FnSplit(@ChainId, ','))` for that input.

Comment: I am using SSMS 2008r. I was able to get the statement to work with just by adding a #2 at the end of the stored procedure then executing. This procedure was copied from the original, since I am new, and I named my stored procedure with a #2 at the end. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a popular function in SQL Server, so I'll assume you're working with that.  Make sure your parameter is of type Varchar(MAX).  @ChainId is passed as your string (ideally for SSRS) and ',' is passed as your delimiter.  In SSRS, if you have a text box for your users to manually enter multiple values, they will enter something like 'value1, value2, value3'.

Test this out:

```
Declare @Yes_No Varchar(Max)
Set @Yes_No = 'y,n'
Select @yes_no
Select * from SplitString('y,n',',')
Select * from SplitString(@Yes_No,',')
```

Your results will be

```
y,n
----
y
n
----
y
n
```

Why I say to use Varchar(Max) and not int, or Varchar(10) for example, is because that would stop the function from reading all the values prematurely.

Try this:

```
Declare @Yes_No Varchar(1)
Set @Yes_No = 'y,n'
Select * from SplitString(@Yes_No,',')
```

The result will be:

```
y
```

The reason is because the function only accepts a value of 1 character in length, and splits that.  As you can see, there isn't much to split.

This is just the way SSRS accepts parameters.  FN_Split isn't necessarily a built-in function, but a widely popular one designed to allow you to pass multiple values to a string, with a pre-specified delimiter.  So make sure you also go to your parameter in the report and specify that it will allow for multiple values.  You will also want to supply a list of potential values for your users to select from.  You'll either do this by manually populating a small list or providing another data source in the form of a stored procedure or table.